# How to determine when a branch was created using Microsoft Web API?

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

Using the Azure DevOps .NET SDK, namespace
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi, to query an Azure repo. How can you find the creation date of a branch?

In this context you have your https://company.visualstudio.com, your token and your repo name. Using only a Web API request, how do you find the history, the first commit, the creation date?

[WebApi doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi?view=azure-devops-dotnet)

[GitBranches documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitbranchstats?view=azure-devops-dotnet)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that there is no direct way to get the creation date and time of a branch. But what you can get is all statuses of a branch with the following endpoint:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>/_apis/git/repositories/<repoId>/refs?includeStatuses=true&filter=heads%2Fmaster
```

The correct repoId you can get from the following endpoint:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/<project>/_apis/git/repositories/
```

The corresponding API reference can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2&tabs=HTTP#gitref)

For testing purposes you can simply use Postman and set the authorization to Basic and enter a Personal Access Token (PAT) as password. Be aware that you do not need to encode it as Base64 if you use Postman.

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Checked with the REST API ([**Refs - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP)), the Client API ([**GitRef Class**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.gitref?view=azure-devops-dotnet)) and the Azure CLI ([**az repos ref list**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/ref?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-ref-list)), there is no built-in property to fetch the created date of branches.

I am afraid that your demand is not able to meet currently.

If you really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for the product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for improving the Azure DevOps products.

Comment: Sure, branches are just pointer to the last commit. But there is no easy way to have the history tab. And GetCommits, does not expose the branch id neither.

Comment: @DragandDrop, Yes. The current Azure DevOps API/CLI have neither a property to show the branch created date nor an option to set to show the branch created date. Maybe, you can consider reporting a feature request as suggested above.